# Using cygwin compiled dll from c source in c#, error read write protected memory on socket() , fork() and similar

Tags: c#, c, sockets, dll, cygwin

I have a source written in C, that uses a lot of socket sender and listener calls, followed by several operating functions. Socket are multicast and also uni cast.

A lot of read write operation happen on it. I compiled it using cygwin, generated an exe and it worked fine on all variants of windows. Meanwhile when I generated a dll from the same and tried to use it in C# through DLLimport it works OK till it reaches to the following line

```
if((sendFd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0)) < 0)
```

Visual studio gives an error:

```
Attempt to read write protected memory, or other memory is corrupt.
```

Without all socket stuff or fork() it works fine doing basic operations such as string manipulations etc.

Comment: There are lots of possible reasons for this, your question doesn't help narrow it down at all.  This is otherwise the reason that .NET programmers use the System.Net.Socket class.

Comment: please tell me you're not trying to use `fork()` in a `dll` that is being used in `C#`/`.NET` - That path leads to madness.

Comment: I M NOT USING FORK() IN THAT DLL, BUT CANT I CREATE A SOCKET., and please this is not such a simple thing that you can easily do in .NET, It s a protocol implementation in C and i cant rewrite it in .NET again.. Does rewriting sounds good to you... thousands of line.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then you're attempting to `[DllImport]` a native library that's been compiled with Cygwin in a .NET assembly?

Well, that is a recipe for disaster:

You are attempting to use two different C Runtime Libraries in the same application.  Cygwin provides its own implementation of various system functions, it's not just a wrapper around the corresponding Windows APIs.  There are several things that could go wrong here:

1. An executable file contains some initialization and startup code that's run prior to invoking `main()`.  This code is automatically generated by the compiler and initializes the C Runtime.  You bypass that code by P/Invoking your DLL.
2. Cygwin uses its own socket code, which needs to make some low-level system calls to interact with the network card - and since Cygwin is using its own implementation, it does this behind the Windows runtime's back.

If you want to use sockets in a native DLL that's used in a .NET Application, you need to use Winsocks and compile it with Microsoft's compiler, so it's linked against the native Windows libraries.

You could, for instance use Visual Studio 2012 Express for Desktop for this.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a dotnet loader which is compatible with cygwin.
You can find it here: https://github.com/smx-smx/EzDotnet

In order to be able to use Cygwin from .NET (without any crashes) the entry point **MUST** be a Cygwin application, compiled and linked under cygwin.

I added a cygwin sample that demonstrates the use of P/Invoke as well as `read(2)` and `write(2)` to redirect the C# stdin/stdout to cygwin (otherwise it wouldn't be visible)

> ./samples/cli/ezdotnet.exe ./CoreCLR/cygcoreclrhost.dll ./samples/Managed/Cygwin/bin/Debug/net5.0/Cygwin.dll ManagedSample.EntryPoint Entry